# Replicaset All Slaves failover scenario issue with mongo 2.2.3 c++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, failover

I'm using c++ 2.2.3 driver to connect to mongo replicaset using ScopedDbConnection. While testing following failover scenario, application just crashes and doesn't recover.

When all the slaves go down, it can not write to master which is obvious but before next mongo operation, I put the slave back up and it can't recover even after.

However, same scenario works good for mongo 2.0 and cpp driver 2.0 with following code. It recovers om next run after I put slave back up.

```
mongo::DBClientBase * MongoKeyValueDataStore::getDbConnection(mongo::ScopedDbConnection * m_scopedDbConnection) {
    DBClientBase * clientDbConnection;
    try {

    clientDbConnection =  m_scopedDbConnection->get();
   // Following is necessary to check and reconnect if server/replicaset came back up
   // works with mongo v2.0 and 2.0 cpp driver but mongo v2.23 and 2.2.3 cpp driver always returns true for isFailed() method
    if (clientDbConnection && clientDbConnection->isFailed()) {
      m_scopedDbConnection->kill();
      return NULL;
    }
    return clientDbConnection;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: When you bring the slave back up does the set have a primary?

Comment: Yes. I bring the slaves back up and one of the server is primary.

Comment: You may wanna post this on mongodb-user, I am no expert with C++ anymore but it might be a bug